What happens when the value of resistances used in a differential input filter for a current sense amplifier circuit is too small?
I am working on a current sense amplifier circuit with the following configuration:

While the circuit works, the filter is not performing as intended. Specifically, it should act as a low-pass filter for the differential input signal with a corner frequency of 2 kHz. However, it is not achieving this goal.
Upon further research, I suspect that the very low values of R2 and R3 are causing R1 to have a significant impact on the filter. This may be creating a large imbalance in the effective resistance of the RC filter from the perspectives of V+ and V-. Is this assumption correct?
I am considering revising the circuit to the following configuration:

Will the revised circuit work as intended? Since R1 is still present, and assuming my earlier assumption about the problem is correct, how can I calculate the specifications of the RC filter based on the values of R1, R2, R3, and C2?
Any insights or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Is IAC truly a current source whose impedance is much greater than 24 ohms of (R1)? If so, then why not C2=3.3uf, R2=R3=0? And does peak current from that source exceed -8mA? If so, you're violating acceptable input range.

The TI datasheet for the INA186A1 is very informative on this topic.  Section 8 discusses signal conditioning of the inputs, the relevant sections are copied below for convenience.  Basically, yes, filtering is recommended, but there are limits as to the values of R2, R3, and C2 (=Rf, Rf, Cf on the app notes below).
For a given corner frequency (Fc), using values for Rf that are too low results in a large value for Cf, causing the input filter to have a low-impedance at the -3dB frequency.  This increases the loading effect of the input filter upon the signal from the current sense resistor (R1 in your schematic), causing the output to under-report the actual current.  Also, in practical terms, this causes the size of C2 to get too large, and its high-frequency performance drops off.
Conversely, using values for Rf that are too high can cause errors due to fact that the input pins of U1 have a known impedance that is not infinite, and that the input pins require some current.
To keep the error under 2%, I suggest selecting the value of Rf to be about 1% of that of the differential resistance between pins IN+ & IN-.  From Figure 8.3, Rin diff is 2MΩ, so choose Rf=2MΩ / 100 = 20kΩ.  So make Rf=R2=R3=22kΩ.
Then select Cf to give the cut-off frequency you require, from Fc = 1 / (4PI.Rf.Cf).
Re-arranging to get Cf, and assuming Fc=2kHz, we get:
Cf = 1 / (4PI.Rf.Fc)  ==>  1.8nF.
Now check that this does not excessively load the current sense resistor.  At worst case, the impedance of C3 is zero, so we compare (R2 + R3) to R1, ie: 44kΩ to 24Ω.  The current pulled by the 44kΩ would be less than 0.1% of the current in R1, so this is an insignificant source of error.
A more accurate assessment of the errors introduced by using a filter can be calculated using equation (5) of the datasheet, refer images below.



Source of images:
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina186.pdf
